# matplotlib: Plot multiple small figures in one big plot

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe pandas_df with 6 input columns: `column_1, column_2, ... , column_6`, and one result column `result`. Now I used the following code to plot the scatter plot for every two input column pairs (so totally I have 6*5/2 = 15 figures). I did the following code 15 times, and each generated a big figure.

I am wondering is there a way to iterate over all possible column pairs, and plot all 15 figures as small figures in one big plot? Thanks!

```
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

pandas_df.plot(x='column_1', y='column_2', kind = 'scatter', c = 'result')
```

Comment: Have you looked through the `seaborn` [api](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/api.html)/[gallery](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/index.html)? [PairGrid](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.PairGrid.html#seaborn.PairGrid) in particular looks like what you are describing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 6), columns=pd.Series(list('123456')).radd('C'))
df
```

[image]

---

***Solution***
Use `itertools` and `matplotlib.pyplot.subplots`

```
from itertools import combinations
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pairs = list(combinations(df.columns, 2))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(len(pairs) // 3, 3, figsize=(15, 12))
for i, pair in enumerate(pairs):
    d = df[list(pair)]
    ax = axes[i // 3, i % 3]
    d.plot.scatter(*pair, ax=ax)

fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: @piRSuared: In fig, axes = plt.subplots(len(pairs) // 3, 3, figsize=(15, 12)), where is "paired" defined? Thanks.